# Datatable-angular export data buttons only creating column headers not data

Tags: datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

Export buttons are only exporting column headers not the data.
I am using datatables in angular5, with serverside processing.

Previously i was using clint-side processing with all data and it was working fine, later i moved for server-side processing with below code.

```
this.table = $('#my-data-table').DataTable({
  serverSide: true,
  filter: false,
  sort: true,
  orderCellsTop: true,
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: [-1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 10, 12],
    orderable: false,
  }],
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    this.draw += 1;
    let info = $('#early-detection-data-table').DataTable().page.info();
    if (info.length > 10) {
      if (info.page > 0) {
        this.offset = ((info.length) * (info.page));
      } else {
        this.offset = (((info.page + 1) * 10) - 10);
      }
    } else {
      this.offset = (((info.page + 1) * 10) - 10);
    }
    this.countNumber = (this.offset + 1);
    let limit = info.length;
    this.patientService.getRecentTransmission(limit.toString(), this.offset.toString(), this.searchCriterian).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.earlyDetections = data;
        let total: number;
        $('.showbox').css('display', 'none');
        //this.setVisiblility();
        if (data[0] && data[0].recordsTotal > 0) {
          total = data[0].recordsTotal;
        } else {
          total = 0;
        }
        callback({
          recordsTotal: total,
          recordsFiltered: total,
          data: [],//JSON.stringify(data),
        });
        console.log(data)
        if (data && data.length != 0) {
          $('td.dataTables_empty').hide();
        } else {
          $('td.dataTables_empty').show();
        }
      });
  }, loadingIndicator: true,
  dom: 'lBfrtip',
  // "order": [[ 7, "desc" ]],
  buttons: {
    buttons: [
      { extend: 'print', className: 'btn btn-primary btn-round' },
      { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn btn-primary btn-round' },
      { extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn btn-primary btn-round' }
    ]
  },
});
```

Please help me and let me know if anything else required from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Last week I had the same issue.
I spent almost 2 days to solve it, the solution that I come with was:
Go to the export buttons library and find where the data was built before exporting to file.

### You will find there:

```
var = data;
data = {
body: [] //actual data of the table
footer: [] //footer of the table if exists 
header:  [] //header of the table
}
```

### In my case here is the data object:

```
body: []
footer: null
header: (4) ["#", "Serial Number", "Filter Type", ""]
__proto__: Object
```

So as you can see the body is empty and that is why you get only headers are shown.
What I did is building the body from the response of the server call and store it on the local storage(so I can access it from everywhere).

### Here is the code sample:

```
 const TableData = [...resp.controllers];
 this.utilService.getDataArrayForExport(TableData, 'Controllers');

    getDataArrayForExport(TableData, TableType) {
        const DataArray = [];
        let formatedObject = {};
        TableData.forEach(function (object, i) {
            switch (TableType) {
                case "Clients":
                    formatedObject = {
                        'email': object.email,
                        'name': object.name,
                        'jobDescription': object.jobDescription,
                        'company': object.company,
                        'countries': object.countries
                    };
                    break;
                case "Controllers":
                    formatedObject = {
                        'controllerSN': object.controllerSN,
                        'filterType': object.filterType
                    };
                    break;
                case "Flushes":
                    const pipeFlush = new DatePipe('en-US');
                    const timeFlush = pipeFlush.transform(object.time, 'short');
                    formatedObject = {
                        'controllerSN': object.controllerId,
                        'description': object.description,
                        'time': timeFlush,
                        'dpBefore': object.dpBefore,
                        'dpAfter': object.dpAfter
                    };
                    break;
                case "Alerts":
                    const pipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
                    const time = pipe.transform(object.time, 'short');
                    formatedObject = {
                        'controllerSN': object.controllerId,
                        'description': object.description,
                        'time': time,
                    };
                    break;
                case "Admins":
                    formatedObject = {
                        'email': object.email,
                        'jobDescription': object.jobDescription,
                        'company': object.company,
                        'countries': object.countries
                    };
                    break;
            }
            const array = [];
            array.push((i + 1).toString());
            $.each(formatedObject, function (key, value) {
                array.push(value);
            });

            DataArray.push(array);
        });
        localStorage.setItem('export', JSON.stringify(DataArray));
        console.dir(DataArray);
    }
```

### Now add a small logic on export if data.body is an empty array:

```
var data = dt.buttons.exportData( config.exportOptions );
    var ddd = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("export"));
        if(data.body.length === 0){
            data.body = ddd;
        }
```

### Now the data object is populated with the data:

```
body: (10) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
footer: null
header: (4) ["#", "Serial Number", "Filter Type", ""]
__proto__: Object
```

So now all set, and you will get all the data export correctly.
I hope my post will help you.

If you have some questions you are welcome to ask :)